# Spring boot Jdbctemplate returns the output in specified format

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using Spring boot for my application. Using jdbctemplate to run MySQL queries.

```
query = "Select * from users";

List<Map<String, Object>> response = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
```

Current output:

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "firstname": "Sam",
            "address": "US"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "firstname": "Alex",
            "address": "US"
        }
]
```

I want to return like below output using jdbctemplate. Is there any method in jdbctemplate to return like below output?

Expected output:

```
[
        [
            "id"
            "firstname"
            "address"
        ],
        [
            1,
            "Sam",
            "US"
        ],
        [
            2,
            "Alex",
            "US"
        ]
]
```

Comment: Try something like this:   List<Object[]> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query).stream().map(row -> row.values().toArray()).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Is your `Current output` the body of a response to a web request?

Comment: @HopeyOne Yes its a web request

Comment: @zatef Is there any existing method in jdbctemplate?

Comment: Doesn't look like such a method exist..... List of methods for jdbctemplate are here, and non of them will return an array of arrays(per your ask). https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html

Comment: JDBC template doesn't support any such method with your requirement. writing a custom extractor is the only way. you can't use row mapper in this case because you would need both data and metadata in the response

Answer (score 6):

You can leverage the [`ResultSetExtractor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html) to map the `ResultSet` into the desired response structure. The columns can be retrieved from the `ResultSet`'s metadata: `rs.getMetadata()`.

```
ResultSetExtractor<List<List<Object>>> resultSetExtractor = new ResultSetExtractor<>() {

    @Override
    public List<List<Object>> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        List<List<Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Object> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(columnNames);

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        for (int col = 1; col <= columnCount; col++) {
            String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(col);
            columnNames.add(columnName);
        }

        while (rs.next()) {
            List<Object> row = new ArrayList<>();
            result.add(row);
            for (int col = 1; col <= columnCount; col++) {
                Object value = rs.getObject(col);
                row.add(value);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};
return jdbcTemplate.query("Select * from user", resultSetExtractor);
```